# Google Oauth2 and Sign in with Google for web

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth

I need to allow my customer to create/view/delete they Gmail's, Contacts, Calendars and Documents (Sheets, Doc's, Images and anything else stored on Drive).

For that purpose, I created API keys on Console, I have access_token, refresh_token etc. and it works OK. Problem is when customer wants to open/edit Sheet or Doc document stored on Drive. He can't do that, because even he gave they permission to add/edit/delete everything, he can't use Sheet application without login.

Now I found this option (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#button_rendering) to use "Sign in with Google for web" and now I must force user to login again to see or edit Sheet from they drive?

Is there any option to login once and to read emails and to edit Sheet's?
I mean, if he gave option to delete a Sheet document - why he can't see it without new login?

Comment: I added openid into scope, when using Oauth2 code, and it seems it works, I'm also logged into Gmail account.

Comment: Hi! From this comment I understand the issue has been resolved. For visibility purposes, would you mind posting the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm logged to Google account when using "openid" inside scope (when using oAuth2).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).